# VLC dummy instance is not closeable

Tags: vlc-media-player

I am currently trying to play a video via the command line without controls.

At this moment everything works fine except that I am not able to close VLC anymore.

Is there a paramter which allows to hide the general controls but lets me close the player at least?

```
vlc.exe -I dummy http://test.com/test.flv
```

Comment: `vlc.exe`, so in Windows, right? A similar command in Linux can be interrupted by Ctrl+C in the console where it runs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using `-I dummy` the video will play until the end or until you stop it

You can use `S` hotkey to stop the video and VLC will exit

The dummy interface will use "no interface" but all Hotkeys are still available

Refs :

- https://wiki.videolan.org/Interfaces/
- https://wiki.videolan.org/QtHotkeys/

Answer (score -1):

`CTRL+Q` more correct way. After pressing `S` the vlc process continues to run.